# How to add or remove specific element from the HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I am having this confusion from a long time now, I want to add a specific element like the `span` in the example between the h1 and h2 tags, but when I click on the button, it added them as the last child of the container, I want to add at the middle of h1 and h2 tags,
And on the remove button, I want to remove that specific element only instead of remove all elements, how can I remove that specific element when clicked on the button

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const btnAdd = document.querySelector('.btnAdd');
const btnRemove = document.querySelector('.btnRemove');

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.innerHTML += `<span>Remove or Add me</span>`;
})

btnRemove.addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.innerHTML += ``;
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Element</h1>
  
  <h2>Element</h2>
</div>

<button class="btnAdd">Add</button>
<button class="btnRemove">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a few more lines of code to create a span element and work with it in the event handlers:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const btnAdd = document.querySelector('.btnAdd');
const btnRemove = document.querySelector('.btnRemove');
const h2 = document.querySelector('h2');
let addClicked = false;
const newNode = document.createElement('span');

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(addClicked) {
    return;
  }
  newNode.innerHTML = 'Remove or Add me';
  container.insertBefore(newNode, h2);
  addClicked = true;
})

btnRemove.addEventListener('click', () => {
  newNode.remove();
  addClicked = false;
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Element</h1>
  
  <h2>Element</h2>
</div>

<button class="btnAdd">Add</button>
<button class="btnRemove">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer only lets you add/remove one single element.

I've updated your snippet as you can run it below - this lets you keep adding elements (by first creating a span element with javascript and then using the `insertBefore` method on the h2 element to insert it dynamically).

The remove button then always deletes the last element that was added, allowing for  a more dynamic list.

You can take this one step further and add a delete button within each span, that upon being clicked, will delete any element wherever they are.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const btnAdd = document.querySelector('.btnAdd');
const btnRemove = document.querySelector('.btnRemove');
const lastElement = document.getElementById('last-element');

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const newSpan = document.createElement('span');
  newSpan.innerHTML = 'Remove or add me';
  container.insertBefore(newSpan, lastElement);
})

btnRemove.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const lastSpan = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.container > span')).pop();
  
  if (lastSpan) {
    container.removeChild(lastSpan);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 id="first-element">Element</h1>
  
  <h2 id="last-element">Element</h2>
</div>

<button class="btnAdd">Add</button>
<button class="btnRemove">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add empty  tag between h tags
- Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. Because it's more safe and fast than `innerHTML`
   cf. [differences between innerHTML and textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innerhtml)

```js
const btnAdd = document.querySelector('.btnAdd');
const btnRemove = document.querySelector('.btnRemove');
const text = document.querySelector('.text');

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
  text.textContent = 'Remove or Add me'
})

btnRemove.addEventListener('click', () => {
  text.textContent = '';
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Element</h1>
  <span class="text"></span>
  <h2>Element</h2>
</div>

<button class="btnAdd">Add</button>
<button class="btnRemove">Remove</button>
```

### EDIT

If you can't define element in html, you can try this code instead.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const h1 = document.querySelector(".container > h1");
const btnAdd = document.querySelector(".btnAdd");
const btnRemove = document.querySelector(".btnRemove");

btnAdd.addEventListener("click", () => {
  h1.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<span>Remove or Add me</span>");
});

btnRemove.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const text = document.querySelector("h1 + span");
  container.removeChild(text);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Element</h1>
  <h2>Element</h2>
</div>

<button class="btnAdd">Add</button>
<button class="btnRemove">Remove</button>
```

Comment: I can't define elements before that, it needs to be added after the button click

Comment: @JoelSmith I add another solution with not fixing any html code.